# Phonegap- Loading images from a specific location

Tags: android, cordova

We are building a Phonegap application basically captures images, saves it in location and then uploads it to a server. We also have a functionality to display the uploaded images for this we are loading a native gallery, below is the code for the same:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    quality: 30,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM
});
```

It's working fine, but it opens entire gallery. I am looking for a way to show up the images from our album I mean it should display our custom album. I searched a lot but couldn't find helpful information. Can someone guide me if it is possible to do this? Or if possible can someone shed some logic to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, it fixed to entire gallery.